# Clean ways to to read multiple httpContext calls in web forms class

Tags: c#, vb.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, clean-architecture

I would like to know if others have options to write the following as "Clean Code"

Also... this is written in VB, but I am happy for suggestions in C#

(I just wrote this in notepad... may not compile, but its the principle I'm questioning)

```
public class MyTest

    public sub new()
    end sub

    public sub SaveSomething(message as string)
        save($"{GetSessionId} == {GetIdentityName} == {message}")   
        if configurationmanager.appsettings("allowSomething") then
            doSomethingElse()
        end if
    end function

    private function GetSessionId as string
        if httpcontext.current?.session?.sessionID isNot Nothing then
            return httpcontext.current.session.sessionID
        else
            return ""
        end if
    end function

    private function GetIdentityName as string
        if httpcontext.current?.user?.identity?.name isNot Nothing then
            return httpcontext.current.user.identity.name
        else
            return ""
        end if
    end function

    private sub save(message)
        dim filePath as string = configurationmanager.appsettings("filePath")
        'some code here to save
    end sub

    private sub doSomethingElse()
        'some code here
    end sub
end class
```

Now, I want to take out all the "httpContext" and "ConfigurationManager" references (cleaner, and so I can unit test etc...)

One method I have considered is creating provider classes for these four situation e.g.

```
_SessionIdProvider as ISessionIdProvider
_IdentityNameProvider as INameProvider
_FilePathProvider as IPathProvider
_AppSettingsAllowSomethingProvider as IAllowSomethingProvider
```

and inject all these in!  which I now think is messy

I have considered a helper class, so one object to inject, which i can use to get these values.. but other places in the solution may need the sessionID for example, with other values that are not in this helper class, so could either have duplicate code, or a massive helper class

Any thoughts? is it messy to inject too many dependencies like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that four is too many dependencies, but it may be on the edge... I suggest that you follow the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and let the client class (`MyTest`) 'design' the interfaces it needs.

Since none of the methods in question take any arguments, however, you can reduce all dependencies to [primitive dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/02/PrimitiveDependencies).

In C# it might look like this:

```
public class MyTest
{
    public MyTest(string sessionId, string identityName, bool allowSomething, string filePath)
    {
        SessionId = sessionId;
        IdentityName = identityName;
        AllowSomething = allowSomething;
        FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public string SessionId { get; }
    public string IdentityName { get; }
    public bool AllowSomething { get; }
    public string FilePath { get; }

    public void SaveSomething(string message)
    {
        Save($"{SessionId} == {IdentityName} == {message}");
        if (allowSomething))
            DoSomethingElse();
    }

    private void Save(message)
    {
        var filePath = FilePath;
        // some code here to save
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

The three values `SessionId`, `IdentityName`, and `AllowSomething` look like they belong to a group of values that relate to the authentication and authorisation, so perhaps they fit better as a [Parameter Object](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).